# ERROR: 'Path is not defined' while I try to start the server

Tags: javascript, express

Hello guys I am trying to use [this](https://www.codementor.io/olatundegaruba/password-reset-using-jwt-ag2pmlck0) tutorial to create a forgot/reset password service for my React Native app. But when I try to start the server I get the following error about path.

`ReferenceError: path is not defined at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/server/services/handlebars.js:16:15)`

Now here is my folder structure

```
-server
 -controllers
   authentication_controller.js
 -models
   user.js
 -services
   handlebars.js
   passport.js
   router.js
 -templates
   forgot-password-email-template.html
   reset-password-email-template.html
 index.js
```

Here is my handlebars.js

```
var hbs = require('nodemailer-express-handlebars'),
    email = process.env.MAILER_EMAIL_ID || 'email@gmail.com',
    password = process.env.MAILER_PASSWORD || 'email_password'
    nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: process.env.MAILER_SERVICE_PROVIDER || 'Gmail',
    auth: {
        user: email,
        password: password
    }
});

var handlebarsOptions = {
    viewEngine: 'handlebars',
    viewPath: path.resolve('../templates'),
    extName: '.html'
};

smtpTransport.use('compile', hbs(handlebarsOptions));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occures here:

```
var handlebarsOptions = {
    viewEngine: 'handlebars',
    viewPath: path.resolve('../templates'),
    extName: '.html'
};
```

The turorial is missing a `require('path')` at the beginning of the `handlebars.js` file:

```
var hbs = require('nodemailer-express-handlebars'),
    email = process.env.MAILER_EMAIL_ID || 'email@gmail.com',
    password = process.env.MAILER_PASSWORD || 'email_password'
    nodemailer = require('nodemailer'),
    path = require('path');
```

Comment: yeah you're right now I got another one `Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]` for this line in router.js `router.route('/auth/forgotPassword')
  .get(AuthenticationController.render_forgot_password_template)
  .post(AuthenticationController.forgotPassword)`

Comment: @MarkusHayner that is an error not related to my answer or to your question